# execute puppet class if file is modified by some package

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet to deploy standardized ubuntu installs as well as configuration files.
I'm facing a problem where installing a certain package (through a dependency), will overwrite a critical config file. Is there a way to monitor whether this file changes (get's overwritten by some package) and restore it's original content?
what would be the best way of achieving this?

This is the class which takes care of configuring `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
class nsswitchconfig {

    # roll out nsswitch   
    class { 'nsswitch':
            passwd => ['compat'],
            group => ['compat'],
            hosts  => ['files'],
            automount => ['files'],
    }

    notify { "hate #8040": message => "work around bug #8040" }

}
```

this is the class which overwrites `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
class desktop {

    include nsswitchconfig

    $package_name = ["ubuntu-desktop" ]
    package { $package_name:
                ensure => latest,
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nsswitch class configures the file, all you need is to make sure it runs **after** the class that overrides it.

So in your case:

```
class { 'nsswitch':
            passwd => ['compat'],
            group => ['compat'],
            hosts  => ['files'],
            automount => ['files'],
            require   => Class['desktop'],
    }
```

should do the trick. (note the require part)